# Bootstrap Popover fail with ajax

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-popover

i would like use the Bootstrap Popover with ajax templates. The next script running good,...

```
$('.popover-trigger').bind('click', function(k) {

                var e=$(this);
title="Jeepieee"
                $.get('/popover/'+e.data('pophtml'),function(d) {
                    e.popover({
                          content: d,
                          container: 'body',
                          title: title,
                          html: true
                        }).popover('show');
                });
});
```

...but, if I open the popover by the first send a ajaxcall, this is right. I open the popover again, it showed me my html, but the html from the popover is old and not ajax-call..

When i use *$().popover('destroy')*, then i have no click-event on my button and it opens nothing.

if I have multiple, will make matters worse.

Answer (score 1):

Loading a content via AJAX in a [Bootstrap popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers) is a very common pattern and, although it is not supported out of the box by Bootstrap, it is very easy to get this functionality with jQuery.

> First we should add a data-poload attribute to the elements you would
>   like to add a pop over to. The content of this attribute should be the
>   url to be loaded (absolute or relative):

```
<a href="#" title="blabla" data-poload="/test.php">blabla</a>
```

> And in JavaScript, preferably in a $(document).ready();

```
$('*[data-poload]').hover(function() {
    var e=$(this);
    e.off('hover');
    $.get(e.data('poload'),function(d) {
        e.popover({content: d}).popover('show');
    });
});
```

> `off('hover')` prevents loading data more than once and `popover()` binds
>   a new hover event. If you want the data to be refreshed at every hover
>   event, you should remove the off.
>
> Please see the working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/6415/) of the example.

Comment: nope! by hover it's running, but not bei click-event. I need click-event, because I work with a form inside in the popover.

Comment: So, Just change hover event to click event. see the demo : [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/22082/)

Comment: No! set under options html of true an have more as one event and the equal response of $get, as is instabil unstable.